# Extend prototype function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have an object that inherits from another object, like so:

```
var a = function ()
{

}
a.prototype.foo = function ()
{
    bar();
}

var b = function ()
{
    a.call(this)
}
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = b;
```

I want to have a method of b that is also named "foo" and extends a's function with the same name.

```
b.prototype.foo = function ()
{
    baz();
    // When .foo() is called, runs both bar() and baz()
}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this in native JavaScript without the aid of libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you can extend the method

```js
function A() {}

A.prototype.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
};

function B() {}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.foo = function() {
  A.prototype.foo.call(this);
  console.log('foo2');
}

var b = new B();

b.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option:

```
b.prototype.foo = function () {
    bar();
    baz();
}
```

But if you make changes to `a.prototype.foo`, you will need to update `b.prototype.foo` with the same logic.

The better option is:

```
b.prototype.foo = function () {
    a.prototype.foo.call(this); 
    baz();
}
```

Now `b.prototype.foo()` calls `a.prototype.foo()` followed by its own internal logic. If you change `a.prototype.foo()`, those changes will be immediately reflected in the behaviour of `b.prototype.foo()` without requiring wider refactoring.

Comment: That always happens. @Georgii Kats just beat me to it with the second solution, so make sure he gets the official answer if it's what you're looking for :)